# How to get image from form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've made a website and can't get image from form. When I inputted all dates and chose image and click on "Submit", image doesn't get from form. I need to get image from form and convert to array of bytes to write in database.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] Products product)
{
    Images image = new Images();
    if (ModelState.IsValid && product != null && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Name)) && product.price != 0 && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.description)) && product.CategoryId != 0)
    {
        //insert
        string query = @"insert into dbo.Product values('" + product.Name + @"'," + product.price + @",'" + product.description + @"',"+ product.CategoryId + @")";

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CommandsConnection");
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
            {
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(myReader);

                myReader.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }

        //select
        string query2 = @"select id from dbo.Product where Name= '" + product.Name + @"'";

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource2 = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CommandsConnection");
        SqlDataReader myReader2;

        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource2))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query2, myCon))
            {
                myReader2 = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table2.Load(myReader2);

                myReader2.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow item in table2.Rows)
        {
            image.id = (int)item["id"];
        }

        //var file = Convert.ToByte(product.image);
        image.image = (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(file, typeof(byte[]));
        Console.WriteLine(image.image);

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("cmscart");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Images>("images");

        collection.InsertOne(image);

        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("Bed");
    }
}
```

When I click on submit I have a `null` in `product.image`. I choose all dates from form and write it in SQL DB and after it, I take **id** for this data and assign **id** to `image.id` and need to take image from `product.image` and assign to `image.image` but before it converted to bytes array and after all write to MongoDB.

These are the models:

```
public class Products
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("image")]
    public byte[] image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Key, Whether the reply has solved the problem or is there any update about this thread? If you have any question about my reply, please let me know freely.

Answer (score 0):

Image property in Products model should be of type IFormFile.

```
public IFormFile image { get; set; }//public string image { get; set; }
```

Also, don't forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to your form.

```
<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Following is the complete sample code in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

View

```
@model MVC_Core_Example.Controllers.Products

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="image" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="image" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MVC_Core_Example.Controllers
{
    public class Products
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public IFormFile image { get; set; }//public string image { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
    public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new Products());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Products product)//IFormCollection collection
        {
            return View(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on submit I have a null in product.image.

The issue is related to the image data type in the Product class, and the image upload method (using tag helper or directly using html file upload element).

In asp.net core application, we could upload the files via the [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile). More detail information, check [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Then, when upload image to the action method, we could use the following methods:

- Using Tag Helper:
  `<input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" type="file" />`

  If using this element, remember add `type="file"` in the input element, you could find the image content from the ProductViewModel model.
- Directly using html file upload element:
  `<input id="file" type="file" name="file" />`

  If using this method, you have to add a IFormFile parameter in the action method and get the image content based on the **name** attribute.

[Note] Using both of the above methods, we have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form tag.

More details information, you could check the following sample code:

Create a ProductViewModel to collect information and upload image:

```
//required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
public class ProductViewModel
{ 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; } 
}
```

Then, in the AddProduct.cshtml page, use the following code to upload image:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
             @*other fields*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
                 @*<input id="file" type="file" name="file" />*@
                <input asp-for="Image" class="form-control" type="file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddProductAsync(ProductViewModel productvm, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //If you are using `<input id="file" type="file" name="file" />` to submit the image, you could get the image from the file.
            if (productvm.Image.Length > 0)
            { 
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await productvm.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                    // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
                    if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
                    {
                        var product = new Product()
                        {
                            imageContent = memoryStream.ToArray()
                        };

                        //_dbContext.Products.Add(product);

                        //await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]